# I can't model sword handle and hand guard correctly

Tags: modeling

I have the handle and the blade but the hand guard is killing me.  I can't figure out how to get that shape while making it look like it fits onto the handle

[image]

[image]

Comment: It might be best to model it as separate objects, or even as separate chunks inside the same mesh object. Unless you specifically need a closed watertight continuous mesh, dealing with those intersection topology might be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was trying to do.  But even making it a separate object didn't help, the shape itself was just hard, I couldn't figure out how to do it while making it look like it fits on the handle neatly.

Comment: Check my answer bellow, see if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be best to model it as as separate chunks inside the same mesh object, or even totally separate objects.

Unless you specifically need a closed watertight continuous mesh (like for 3D printing or fabrication), dealing with those intersection topologies might be more trouble than it's worth. Just let them intersect nicely inside the handle object, and save a lot of work and additional faces trying to solve the weld between the handle and the guard.

So if you don't mind a separate object, or like a more non destructive workflow, you can easily do it with a combination of *Mirror* + *Array Modifier*.

Just add a new cylinder object, and erase $3/4$ of it, so you can add a *Mirror Modifier* to it in X and Y axis.

Add a central loop cut, bevel it, then extrude one of the side faces. Don't forget to erase the inside faces along the mirror seam, or it will lead to bad shading artifacts.

Add a *Subsurf* modifier, subdivide the previously extruded face and add necessary control loops in both directions to control the shape of the spike.

[image: Hand Guard Spike model]

Then just use an *Array* modifier to duplicate it along its length. Add an empty object, rotate in 90º about the Z axis, then assign it to *Object Offset* slot of the *Array* modifier, so each additional spike is rotated 90º in relation to the previous one.

Adjust the number of items and apply the modifiers if you need a static mesh.

[image: Hand Guard Spike Array]

Comment: That helps with the barbs but the main problem I'm having is creating that triangle that runs up the middle of the blade.  I can't get it to look good when connecting to the handle and also have those arms coming off of it.  I guess I'll have to make that one piece 3 different objects.

Comment: It is totally doable as a single connected mesh, but modeling it as a three piece separate object will save you a lot of headache. Connecting hard edge sharp objects with rounded ones is always troublesome

Comment: Yeah, I was able to make that triangle since I didn't have to worry about where I was going to extrude those arms.  Got it.